# Generating friendly id sequence in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a bunch of relationships where I would like to create a friendly id for the child objects so that I can have friendlier URLs.

Every time I create a child object for a particular parent object I would like to automatically include a friendly id which increments sequentially. So the first child would have friendly id 1, the second would have friendly id 2, etc. I don't want to reuse id's if children are deleted.  To complicate matters, there are many such relationships that I would like to do this for.

Currently I'm caching some state on the parent node and using that to populate the friendly id when creating children:

```
CREATE (o:Foo {name: 'parent', nextChildId: 1})

MATCH (o:Foo)
WHERE o.name = 'parent'
CREATE (o)-[:HAS]->(c:Child {name: 'child1', friendlyId: o.nextChildId})
SET o.nextChildId = o.nextChildId + 1

MATCH (o:Foo)
WHERE o.name = 'parent'
CREATE (o)-[:HAS]->(c:Child {name: 'child2', friendlyId: o.nextChildId})
SET o.nextChildId = o.nextChildId + 1
```

The problem is that there is a chance that two children will end up with the same friendly id since two clients could try and create children at the same time. I'm not sure how to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else that is looking to do this, I got a workaround from the Neo4j Google group. The trick is to create a lock on the node by removing a non-existent property. This serializes access to the node and prevents multiple children from getting the same id.

```
CREATE (o:Foo {name: 'parent', nextChildId: 1})

MATCH (o:Foo)
WHERE o.name = 'parent'
REMOVE o.lock  // non-existent property
CREATE (o)-[:HAS]->(c:Child {name: 'child1', friendlyId: o.nextChildId})
SET o.nextChildId = o.nextChildId + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j is fully [ACID compliant](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/transactions.html). You can run this in a transaction with `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level and acquiring the lock on the node of interest. Remember however that this might be degrade the performance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all Cypher queries are run within a transaction, but I'm not sure how to configure the isolation level (they all get executed as READ_COMMITED). I'm using the REST endpoint for Neo4j server with the golang library 'github.com/jmcvetta/neo4j'.

Comment: @Bill You have to programatically acquire the lock. Follow here http://api.neo4j.org/1.9.M05/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html. But not sure how to specify the isolation level. Will try to find.

Comment: Looks like it is not possible yet over the REST API. I've filed a feature request with Neo4j.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!