# Auto generation of Sequence Numbers for nodes in Cypher REST API - Neo4J

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher

I have a requirement to auto generate sequence numbers when inserting nodes into neo4j db, this sequence # will be like an id to the node and can be used to generate external url's to access that node directly from the UI.

This is similar to the auto generation of sequence property in mysql, how can we do this in neo4j via Cypher ? I did some research and found these links

[Generating friendly id sequence in Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391681/generating-friendly-id-sequence-in-neo4j)

http://neo4j.com/api_docs//1.9.M05/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html

However these links are useful when I'm doing this programatically in transactional mode, in my case it's all using Cypher REST API.

Pls advise.

Thanks,

Deepesh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `MERGE` to mimic sequences:

```
MERGE (s:Sequence {name:'mysequenceName'})
ON CREATE s.current = 0
ON MATCH s.current=s.current+1
WITH s.current as sequenceCounter
MATCH .... <-- your statement continues here
```

Comment: Is there a version of this that works in multithreaded environments?

Comment: Stefan - so basically you are suggesting a node which keeps a counter and we use refer to it everytime before a merge or create of a node that needs that sequence ? Ok this works in my case as of now, thanks but as we grow to a multithreaded env, I believe this will impact, so back to John's question. At some point late how will the lock be managed when two queries are trying to run this at the same time ?

Comment: At a high level - I think Neo4J should have this feature of generating sequence numbers at node/label/rel level, this will eliminate the need to use such custom implementations.

Comment: The sketched approach is threadsafe since the `MERGE` will lock the sequence node. However multiple concurrent threads will need to wait and get processed sequentially when getting a new sequence value. Compared to RDBMS graph dbs typically don't need unique ids for their own, that's why this is not a core feature.

Comment: Since 2014 the syntax has changed a bit. Now it is required to use `ON CREATE SET s.current = 0` and `ON MATCH SET s.current=s.current+1`. Otherwise, it still works well. @stefan-armbruster is there now a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If your unique ID does not need to be numeric nor sequential, you can just generate and use a GUID whenever you want to create a node. You have to do this programmatically, and you should [pass the value as a parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/query-create.html#_use_parameters_with_create), but there should be good libraries for GUID generation in all languages and for all platforms.

Comment: Thanks Cybersam for the inputs however we are not doing this programmatically in the code, as of now we are relying on making REST API calls to neo4j and have everything via Cypher, so the question was more Cypher oriented.